# What does Conway mean by "length" of a triangle?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://psm73.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/conway.pdf) and on page 103/104, he said:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I didn't understand why he meant by "length of T" and why $|g(z)|\le \epsilon/l$ for any $z$ on $T_1$ and because of that $|\int_{T_1}g|\le \epsilon$.

Comment: In this proof, it seems to mean the perimeter of triangle. (in any event, if you replace the word "length" by "perimeter" in the proof, the arguments continue to work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained at the bottom of p. 100 in the book, the length of a triangle is the length of its perimeter.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're completely right! Do you know  which theorem he used when he said $|\int_{T_1}g|\le \epsilon$?

Comment: That's 1.17(b).  But you should also know it as the [M-L inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma).